# Checking whether a particular position in the map has any obstacle

Tags: ros, obstacle-avoidance, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to check whether a particular position in the map has any obstacle. I want to check if at any particular location (x,y) the corresponding cell has any obstacle or not. How to do that using costmap in ros ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225271/checking-whether-a-particular-position-in-the-map-has-any-obstacle/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-05**:
did you find a solution for this?

**Comment by [samir menaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/52863/samir-menaa/) on 2020-06-03**:
Hello, have found a solution to this. i am searching for he same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on where you want to do the check, seperate node (probably subscriber), node that has the costmap as a member.

I guess it is straight forward if the costmap is  member, than translate the coordinate to the relevant cell (e.g. using the `worldToMap` [function](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L143)), check the costs (e.g. using the `getCost` [function](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L116)) and then compare against the [cost values](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/cost_values.h)).

Maybe there is a more direct way, but I don't know.

If it is a seperate node where you subscribe to, the way should be the same...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on 2016-01-28**:
Thank You....what if we need to take the footprint of the robot into account, i.e., not to consider the robot as a point object ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
This is what the costs are for. So you need to use the `inflation_layer` which gets inflated depending on the robot footprint. There are costs for "definitely in collision" and "maybe in collision", as they use the inscribed and curcumscribed radius, repsecitvely.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
Check out http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d for more information on the cost calculation and how the footprints are used.

**Comment by [Omair Khalid](https://answers.ros.org/users/26951/omair-khalid/) on 2021-06-14**:
Do I need to create another costmap object exactly similar to what is already running in the nav stack, and then add my custom function? Or, is there a simpler way to instantiate a costmap object with the latest costmap information (including current information from all the layers)?

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2022-01-04**:
@Omair Khalid did you find the solution ?